# Search data who have same tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm try to create a simple search based on jquery and json file, i want to get data who have same `tag` after searching for a specific `Title` here is the json

```
[
    {
        "title": "   Title one  ",
        "description": "  description one  ",
        "link": "http://expample1.com",
        "tag": {
            "tag1": "Stackoverflow",
            "tag2": "Demo one"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "   Title Two  ",
        "description": "   description Two  ",
        "link": "http://expample2.com",
        "tag": {
            "tag1": "Stackoverflow",
            "tag2": "Demo two"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "   Title Three  ",
        "description": "   description Three  ",
        "link": "http://expample3.com",
        "tag": {
            "tag1": "Tag thre",
            "tag2": "Demo Three"
        }
    }
]
```

and here is a DEMO on [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xhnyueo/)

for example when i type **Title one** i want to show the **Title one** and **title two** because they have same `tag1: stackoverflow`

Comment: @ what is your expected out put??

Comment: **Title one** and **title Two** because they same **tag2: stackoverflow**

Comment: you want to also find in nested tag like "tag1"?

Comment: yeah who have same tag1 or tag2 :)

Comment: @ Redai made some changes [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u7dqe4ak/)

Comment: its work 100% Thnx @ozil

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

html code

```
<div class="ui-widget">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
        <div id="res"></div>
    </div>
```

javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').bind("enterKey",function(e){
        var want = $("#search").val();
        var myExp = new RegExp(want, "i");
         var data = [
    {
        "titre": "   Title one  ",
        "description": "  description one  ",
        "link": "http://expample1.com",
        "tag": {
            "tag1": "Stackoverflow",
            "tag2": "Demo one"
        }
    },
    {
        "titre": "   Title Two  ",
        "description": "   description Two  ",
        "link": "http://expample2.com",
        "tag": {
            "tag1": "Stackoverflow",
            "tag2": "Demo two"
        }
    },
    {
        "titre": "   Title Three  ",
        "description": "   description Three  ",
        "link": "http://expample3.com",
        "tag": {
            "tag1": "Tag thre",
            "tag2": "Demo Three"
        }
    }
];
            var output = '<ul class="results">';
            var bool = false;
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                for(var prop in val) {
                    console.log(prop);
                    console.log(typeof val[prop]);
                    if(typeof val[prop] ==  'object') {
                        output += checkNestedTag(want, val[prop]);
                    }
                    if(prop == want && typeof val[want] !=  'object') {
                        output += '<li>';
                        output += '<h3>'+ val[want]+'</a></h3>';
                        output += '</li>';
                    } else if(typeof val[want] ==  'object')
                        bool = true;
                }
            });

            if(bool)
                output += '<li>Value is in object</li>';
            output += '</ul>';
            $("#res").html(output);
        });
    $('#search').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        }
    });

});


function checkNestedTag(want, val) {

    var output = '';
    for(var prop in val) {

        if(typeof val[prop] ==  'object') {
            output += checkNestedTag(want, val[prop]);
        }
        if(prop == want) {
            output += '<li>';
            output += '<h3>'+ val[want]+'</a></h3>';
            output += '</li>';
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

i'm not sure but i think it's helpful to you.
http://jsfiddle.net/szvvh8dL/1/

Answer (score -1):

Here you go with a basic search. Now you only have to loop again and check for same tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xhnyueo/3/

My search algorithm is:

```
$('#search').on("keyup", function() {
    $("#res").empty();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i].titre.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1) {
            var output = '<li>';
            output += '<h3><a href='+ data[i].link +' target="blank">'+ data[i].titre + '</a></h3>';
            output += '<span>'+ data[i].description +'</span>';
            output += '<h6>'+ data[i].tag.tag1 +''+ data[i].tag.tag2 +'</h6>';
            output += '<h6></h6>';
            output += '</li>';
            $("#res").append(output);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not what he wants.. on searching for the titre he needs to show only those elements having the same tags inside in it. As for your code it just searches the titre and shows it.

Comment: Reda, i posted a fiddle link (demo). @Kushal yes i know what he want but this is not a plattform for coding request. You ask a question and do the main work by yourself so i gave him an hint how to search...